# Why can I assign a negative number to an unsigned integer variable?

Tags: rust

Why isn't the following Rust-Code failing?!

```
fn main() {
    let a:usize = -2;
    assert!(a == -2);
}
```

- I would expect a compile time error, since I'm trying to assign a signed number to an unsigned variable.
- I would also expect the assertion to fail, since `a` can't be negative.

Neither of both is happening, why?

Shouldn't the compiler protect me from common overflow issues?

Comment: It coverted to usize implicitly

Comment: I know, but why would the compiler allow me to do something like this!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Up until now, Rust has defined the semantics of underflow and overflow on integral types as wrap-around modulo 2. Therefore, assigning `-2` to an unsigned integer is simply asking for its maximum minus one.

Those semantics are [being challenged right now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/560) and the gist of it is that for 1.0 underflow and overflow will yield an unspecified value (and possibly `panic!`); though for performance reasons the tests will only be systemic in Debug mode and will be disabled by default in Release mode.

In this new direction, it would be reasonable to consider assigning a negative value to an unsigned integer an error, and I can only invite you to chime in on the linked RFC so as to voice your concern.

Comment: Is this really a case of under/overflow? I was under the impression that under/overflow always required a math operation (add, subtract, etc.).

Comment: @Shepmaster: I am not sure there is an exact definition, I certainly do not see why a lossy conversation could not be considered to either underflow or overflow. Whether Rust chooses to qualify it so hinges on the RFC though.

Comment: Usually wraparound is a behavior (possibly well-defined) and overflow is the name of an error condition. In C, unsigned arithmetic wraps around. In C, signed addition may overflow.

Comment: Looks like theres been discussion in [issue #5477](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/5477) and the [forum](http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/a-tale-of-twos-complement/1062/61)